# why is an NSInteger appearing different in log console than in call stack variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode5

I have a variable with an NSInteger type.. if I set a breakpoint on the variable and print it's output into the log, I get the expected value (ie 0).. however it looks very different on the debugger stacktrace variable list (180821440).. can someone explain what's going on?

[image]

I'm running Xcode 5.1.1 with Apple LLVM 5.1 having a `None` optimization level for the compiler

Comment: taxiAmount is not an object, so printing it with "po" makes no sense. Use "p" instead.

Comment: @MartinR Actually it does work.  This is from using `lldb` at the command line : `(lldb) p ip
(uint32_t) $0 = 39452930
(lldb) po ip
39452930`

Comment: (not well formatted, but `p` and `po` have the same effect with LLDB from Xcode 5.1.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the discussion of [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) and [Droppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588973/droppy) above.. I figured out this was happening.

In the original code I was getting the `taxiAmount` value from an http call like so:

```
[serverGateway_ getTaxiAmountWithCoordinate:coordBlock onSuccessBlock:^(NSData *responseData)
 {
     [parser_ parseTaxiAmountWithData:responseData onSuccessBlock:^(NSNumber *taxiAmount)
     {
          [cityManager_ setTaxiAmount:taxiAmount];
```

so I was sending an `NSNumber` value to a `NSInteger` varialbe

```
- (void)setTaxiAmount:(NSInteger)taxiAmount
{
    taxiAmount_ = taxiAmount;
}
```

in this case typing `po taxiAmount` returned 0, whereas `p taxiAmount` returned 180520272:

so what was causing this whole hoopala was treating a NSNumber as an NSInteger.. obviously correcting the line to

```
[cityManager_ setTaxiAmount:[taxiAmount integerValue]];
```

fixed the problem (and cleared the confusion)

[image]

Comment: Did the compiler not warn about an "integer to pointer conversion"?

Comment: Is `cityManager_` an id and not a specific type, then?